# Why TWebbrowser IHTMLElement.click fails while mouse click succeeds

Tags: javascript, delphi, onclick, twebbrowser

I'm trying to auto-fill a web page. Filling input elements and navigating with buttons works fine. Just the final "Save" button fails when programmatically clicking on it, while clicking with the mouse succeeds. The Save button appears to contain some Javascript. In the document it looks like this:

```html
<a title="Enregistrer / Save"
 class="btn--icon icon-save ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
 id="_save"
 onclick="
  $('#overlayLoading').dialog('open');
  $('#form_model').attr('action', 'https://<some url>');
  $('#form_model').submit();"
 abp="1909">
<span
 class="ui-button-text"
 abp="1910">Enregistrer<br
 abp="1911">
 <span
  lang="en"
  abp="1912">Save
 </span>
 </span>
</a>
```

I tried 3 different approaches:

First approach:

1. Search for `IHTMLelement` with id `"_save"` and do `.click()`
2. `Navigate()` to the URL that is embedded in the element
3. Executing the JavaScript like this

   ```
   var
     Script: string;
     DocPtr: IHTMLDocument2;
     WinPtr: IHTMLWindow2;

   Script :=
       '$(''#overlayLoading'').dialog(''open'');'+
       '$(''#form_model'').attr(''action'', ''https://<some url>'');'
       '$(''#form_model'').submit();';
   if Supports(WB.Document, IHTMLDocument2, DocPtr) and
     Supports(DocPtr.parentWindow, IHTMLWindow2, WinPtr) then
      WinPtr.execScript(Script, 'javascript');
   ```

All 3 methods do seem to work, but the web server returns an error page. When I instead click on the button presented in the `TWebBrowser` with the mouse, the web server returns success.

What is the physical click doing differently from the programmic click?

Comment: Your "Save" button is not a button at all, it is a `<span>` inside of an `<a>` hyperlink.  So make sure you are `click()`ing on the `<a>` object, not on the `<span>` object. However, if this is inside a `<form>`, then simply use the DOM to set the `<form>`'s `action` and `submit()` it, just like the JS code is doing (ignore the dialog portion).

Comment: @Remy - First things first I would like to thank you for your years long outstanding support to the community! After further testing it turned out that I didn't do anything wrong but some timing. After filling the form and before `click`ing the element I just have to wait a second and all is well. So the problem is solved. Thank you anyways for your response.